# Content Permissions in Orchard

Tags: permissions, navigation, orchardcms

In an OrchardCms site, I need to create a hierarchical menu where I can show and hide menu items by user role.  What is the best way to approach this?

One possible way would be to create and manage two menu's, each pertaining to a different layer where the layer rule species the respective Role.  However, this means managing two Menu's which is not ideal.  Many items in each menu would need to be duplicated.

Another way would be to create a custom Menu Part.  The downside here is it seems like overkill.

Or am I on the wrong track completely, should I be looking more at filtering content items by role instead?  In this scenario, I believe I would still need a way to specify menu filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Advanced Menu (available from the gallery) does menu trimming based on permissions.

Update: my bad. Try Quanta instead (part of the Science project). Should work well with Cartography.

Comment: I have tried playing with Advanced Menu but I don't see any trimming options.  Am I missing something, or any tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create multiple menus filtered by role in layers with [this simple PCG.RoleLayer module](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.PCG.RoleLayer). You will still have to make separate menus though, and it doesn't restrict url access unless you change permissions.

After enabling the module, you can create rules for roles. For example,

```
role("Administrator")
```

Would make that layer only visible to those with the administrator role.